# Change the location of the user photos

Tags: users, user-profile

Is it possible to change the default location users upload their profile photos to? Right now they are stored in `/admin/resources/userphotos/` which for me is not preferable for some reasons. I’d rather have them somewhere in `html/img/member` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a custom asset field for the users' profile images and hide the default one in the CP.

Here's a plugin to do this: [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) by Lindsey D

Comment: Hackish, but not such a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Profile photos are saved to `craft/storage/userphotos/` by default.

I don't know if you can change the path of `userphotos` specifically, but what you can do is to change the path of `craft/storage/` to your liking by adding this to your `index.php`:

```php
define('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../assets/storage").'/');
```

Other interesting path constants that you can overwrite like this are:

- `CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH`
- `CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH`
- `CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH`
- `CRAFT_TRANSLATIONS_PATH`

Comment: (waited to long to edit the above comment)

That’s not exactly what i am aiming at though. I would like to treat userphotos the same way regular assets are being handled. That includes initial transforms at upload which i don’t want. Plus i would rather not have my visitors being able to figure out the system the site is running on by looking up the image path. That’s a requirement right now.

I just could add another asset-field to the users field layout but that would result in a UI conflict since there would be two photo settings.

Comment: Yeah I knew that this is not exactly what you were after, @Marcus ;)